# Is it possible to do this without resorting to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

[This demo](http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/equalheights.html), which goes along with [this article](http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/308/equal-height-boxes-with-javascript), succintly describes what I need to do. However I am not impressed by the use of javascript for something that should be possible in pure CSS.

The articles referenced (which I also found independently when looking for a way in CSS) don't perform the same function as the watchmaker demo - [the 456 boxes demo](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/equal_height_ii/) doesn't slide under the other boxes when the screen width gets too small.

I've been playing about with the article code and trying various ideas in CSS, but nothing lays out correctly. Also I would prefer progressive enhancement over graceful degradation.

Comment: You want to have boxes with different css height properties rendered at the same height, and do it in css? Why not just...give them the same height?

Comment: The boxes are going to have a variable amount of content which isn't known beforehand. He wants them all to automatically be as large as the largest one, regardless of content.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments for my answer below, this is now possible using current CSS standards. You may want to review whether my answer should still be the accepted one.

Comment: It's not 100% correct but closer and probably fixable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I wanted to bubble up the answer you should be using now: [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/). The original demo from the question is long gone, but the markup was this ([courtesy of the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20131201022947/http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/equalheights.html)):

```
<div id="one">I am 150px high</div>
<div id="two">I am 200px high</div>
<div id="three">I am 120px high</div>
<div id="four">I am 300px high</div>
```

In order to equalize the heights using flexbox, you would need to have a container wrapped around them:

```
<div class="container container--equal-children">
  <!-- those four divs -->
</div>
```

Setting that to `display: flex` and setting `align-items` to "stretch" gives the desired effect:

```
.container--equal-children {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Once that’s in place, you can skip the whole sizing thing and let the children flex to fill 1/4 the space:

```
.container--equal-children #one,
.container--equal-children #two,
.container--equal-children #three,
.container--equal-children #four {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}
```

They will all automatically be the same height.

I put together [a CodePen that lets you toggle the flexbox rules on and off](http://codepen.io/aarongustafson/pen/XmdWea). It’s worth noting only the toggling functionality requires JS. There are also some "for presentation only" style rules I’ve added (which are noted) to demonstrate the design behavior.

Comment: While reading and seeing that the flex box is still a working draft, my initial concern was that support cross browsers would be patchy, but on my phone (Chrome) and on my desktop (Chrome, IE) it works fine.  There is one issue left: When you resize they don't reorder (resize the WaybackMachine demo).

Comment: @graham.reeds I can’t seem to get the order to change in the WayBack version, but you can adjust the order using Flexbox too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Shrink the screen down smaller than the 4 boxes. The 4th box drops below the other 3.

Comment: Oh ok, I gotcha now. You can use `flex-wrap`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

For more, check out this piece I wrote up: https://www.aaron-gustafson.com/notebook/playing-with-flexbox-and-quantity-queries/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there really isn't a good way to do it in pure CSS.  I assume that you want a dynamic height of containers based on a single parent container.  Cross-browser issues make it an absolute nightmare, and the relatively small amount of JavaScript needed to accomplish the effect, IMO, is a better approach than trying to maintain really ugly and nasty CSS rules, having to import other CSS rules to fix things in certain browsers, etc, etc.

There's a reason these "equal heights" scripts even exist, and it's because of how much of a hassle the effect in pure CSS is.

I would stick with the JavaScript solution.

Comment: This answer was great in its day, but fortunately browsers have improved. Aaron's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32613307/409915) about flexbox is a great solution today.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for your note -- I agree. Upvote for Aaron, and a nudge for OP to decide what to do about my accepted answer.

Comment: You are right @Cory.  A lot has changed in the past 6 years since I wrote that question!

Answer (score 2):

This is something which you'd think would be simple but is actually really tricky.

The "sliding under" aspect isn't really related to maintaining the same size. That's just how floating works. They probably have a rule like:

```
.box { float: left }
```

with markup like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

If they gave .container a fixed width, that would prevent the .box's from sliding under each other.

If all you're looking for is to have background colors under various boxes of fixed width, there is an easy way to accomplish this without JS.

You can give .container a background image that has the backgrounds for all the boxes and tiles vertically. With your first example, it would be only a few pixels high with a 200 px section of orange, 200px of blue, 200px of red, and 200px of green.

Since if you "clear" the .container it grows to contain all the boxes, the background boxes would appear to all be the same height.

Anything more complicated such as vertically centering the text in the second example, and you're probably better off going with one of the JS scripts to even out the boxes.